# Use FLOOR on SUM's result

Tags: google-sheets, sum, floor

I'm using the following formula to get a 7-day average value

```
SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(B2:B500, "limit 7 offset " & COUNTA(B2:B500)-7))) / 7
```

If I wrap that in FLOOR the value changes wildly:

```
FLOOR(SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(B2:B500, "limit 7 offset " & COUNTA(B2:B500)-7))) / 7, 1.1)
```

I'm assuming it's because it is flooring all the values used in the sum, as opposed to the final result of the sum function?

Is there are a way to make it resolve the sum and then floor the result? Or whatever else it is that's wrong with my formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the second parameter to `floor()` is correct. You are probably looking for `0.1` rather that `1.1`. Compare:

`=floor(9.55, 0.1)` → `9.5`

`=floor(9.55, 1.1)` → `8.8`

Comment: Ah. I thought 1.1 just specified that I wanted 1 decimal. What's the difference between those two?

Comment: See the [floor()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093487) help page.

Comment: I don't get it. The floor function comes built-in with a multiplication parameter? Doesn't matter anyway. The thing I really wanted was ROUND.

Comment: It may have sounded like that, but you can't ask a single question without assuming something. Otherwise every question would start with a languageless dissertation establishing a common universal assumptionless reference frame before moving forward. Which would take approximately all the time in the world.

Comment: A solid point if not for the fact I already had the answer for how to round things. But let's pretend that the best way to ask a question is to assume nothing, think nothing and just throw 100% of a problem at someone. As opposed to narrowing down what you assume the problem to be.